# How to handle options with a default

Tags: scala

```
val a = user.type match {
  case Member => doSomething(if(user.location.isDefined) user.location.get.name else "")
}
```

I want to safely access the user.location which is a Option[Location] if it exists, otherwise just use an empty string.

```
case class Location(id: Int, name: String)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Simply:

```
 doSomething(user.location.map(_.name).getOrElse(""))
```

Comment: sorry I updated my question to location instead of middleName, where location is a case class/model.

Comment: @coolbreeze That's still the correct answer, effectively `getOrElse`

Comment: Since Location is an option, doing this won't work:  ```  user.getOrElse("") ``` since the property is a Location not a string.

Comment: @coolbreeze `doSomething(user.location.map(_.name).getOrElse(""))`

Answer (score 3):

Best way to "deep match" into an Option that is nested inside some other object is through a structural pattern match, finally giving a variable name to the desired value and using it in the right side of =>.

I don't know what your "Member" class looks like, but assume that it has two parameters, since we don't care about the first one we put an underscore there "_" and then refer directly to the Location class in the second param, like this:

```
val a = user match {
  case Member(_, Location(_, Some(name))) => doSomething(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
val a = user.type match {
  case Member(id, type) if(user.location.isDefined) => doSomething(user.location.get.name)
}
```

If your Member is a case class with attributes id, type for example.

Comment: this doesn't compile

Comment: Okay you need to use the extraction. I'll add it for completeness sake.

Comment: there is a loose `else`

Comment: There are already quite better answers. But is it a loose else returning Unit  or is it a matching error?

Comment: this is not valid syntax

Comment: If Iam not using type as a literal without ` I can compile it. It would be nice if you can tell me where my error is.

Comment: `doSomething(user.location.get.name else "")` <--- loose `else`

Comment: Oh totally didn't get that. I'm ashamed.